# What's a Late Answer?

Tags: support

Under the review tab, there's a category "Late Answers" for review.  I can't locate a definition of a late answer in the FAQ or anywhere else.

So, Q: What's a "late answer"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A late answer is an answer which was posted a long time after the latest activity on the question.  (Not sure the exact threshold.  Seems to be somewhere in the 6 month range)

These are pulled out for special review because they often wind up turning out to have been people arriving from search engines who've posted a "Thanks" or "This was useful" message as an answer, or follow-up/related questions which should have been asked as separate questions, or similar problems related to people assuming that StackExchange works like forum software, rather than as a Q&A site.

In general, you can review them exactly as you review any other answer.  Check that they're actually a real answer to the question, and that they wouldn't have been more appropriate as a comment.  If all looks fine, then everything's fine.  :)

Comment: Thanks Trevor.  Seems like this explanation should be written somewhere on the site, no?